# Is it possible to model the rotation of a bowl as a function of time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

I was watching a video where someone spun a bowl, and then let it rotate until it eventually stopped and fell flat onto the table. I was wondering if it is possible to model the rotation of a bowl as a function of time given an initial force applied to the bowl. I've made a little diagram below to try to show what I mean about the bowl's rotation. It is just an upside down bown moving around on a table.

[image: First timestep]

[image: Second timestep]

[image: Third Timestep]

Is this type of movement chaotic? Can it be modelled by some function `f(t)`?

Comment: This is a classic problem that is discussed in most mechanics textbooks that deal with rigid body dynamics. It is the same problem as rolling a penny, but is rather too complicated for an answer here.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn’t realize that

Comment: You can check out a similar example which is Euler's disk. For a penny or disk, steady motion and energy can be modeled but complicated.  It has been the subject of a number of scientific papers.